# Submit checkout form with JS after processing payment on checkout page only

Tags: magento2, javascript, onepage-checkout, payment-gateway

I've integrated some custom payment module. I am getting trouble with form submission with JS  after payment response. 
I need to submit the checkout form on click of **place order but with JS** and that only after processing the payment.

How can I place an order with JS?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your case. But, there is a call back function after placing order.

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js

```
    /**
     * After place order callback
     */
    afterPlaceOrder: function () {
        // Override this function and put after place order logic here
    },
```

Put this function in your custom payment method renderer component.

---

Update with the comment:

> Can i first trigger my function in`JS` AND then after processing the
>   payment trigger the placeorder. How is this possible?

You can write your own `placeOrder` in your payment method renderer component.

Comment: Thanks for this. 
Can i first trigger my function in` JS ` AND then after processing the  payment trigger the  `placeorder`. How is this possible?

Comment: You can write your own `placeOrder` in your payment method renderer component.

Comment: iostpay-method.js in `method-renderer`
`define(
    [
     'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/payment/iostpay'
            },
            getMailingAddress: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
    });});
`

Comment: This is iostpay-method.js in `method-renderer`

Comment: Your payment method should extend from `view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js` component. So, please, take a look at this file to see how to implement `placeOrder` function.

Comment: how can I handle placeorder click? here is my default.js
`define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list'
    ],
    function (
        Component,
        rendererList
    ) {
        'use strict';
        rendererList.push(
            {
                type: 'iostpay',
                component: 'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/js/view/payment/method-renderer/iostpay-method'
            }
        );
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);`

Comment: Add `placeOrder` function inside `Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/js/view/payment/method-renderer/iostpay-method`.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped to trigger my method.
now, how can I successfully place-order, after the successful payment.

Comment: Ok, you're welcome!

Comment: What can i do to placeOrder after processing payment here?

`placeOrder: function(){
    
    
    var getresp = transfer() ;
      
    
   }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100961/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-garry).